# How to change Font type in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ngui

How do I program it so that I can change the font type to: Coalition or Arial...

Here is my current code...

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class InvSlotHandler : MonoBehaviour {

    private int excess = 1;
    UILabel lbl;

    void Start() {

        GameObject label = new GameObject();
        lbl = label.AddComponent<UILabel>();

        label.transform.name = "#QTY";
        lbl.fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal;
        lbl.fontSize = 15;
        lbl.alignment = NGUIText.Alignment.Right;

        NGUITools.AddChild (gameObject.transform.gameObject, label.gameObject);
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        lbl.text = gameObject.transform.childCount - excess + "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to change the font of a **UILabel** that uses a **dynamic font** in **NGUI**.

The label shows some text in the original font for 2 seconds, then switches to the other font (the one you assign to *otherFont* in the inspector)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ChangeFont : MonoBehaviour {

    public UILabel label; 
    public Font otherFont;

    IEnumerator Start() {
        label.text = "This is a bit of text"; //show text
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f); //wait 2 seconds
        label.trueTypeFont = otherFont; //change font
    }

}
```

If your label was set to use a **bitmap font**, you'd assign a **UIFont** to **label.bitmapFont** instead.

Comment: The above code assumes that you will manually assign **UILabel label**.

Comment: That is correct. As far as I know there is no way to get a list of available Fonts at runtime. You can however get the default built-in Arial font doing the following:
    
    label.trueTypeFont = Resources.GetBuiltinResource(typeof(Font), "Arial.ttf") as Font;

Comment: Oh thanks: Resources.GetBuiltinResource(typeof(Font), "Arial.ttf")
Did the trick