# How to set a font for a UI Text in Unity 3D programmatically

Tags: unity-game-engine

in my game I have a UI Text that I've called "label", and I want to set its font programmatically. I've tried to do this:

```
label.GetComponent<Text>().font="Arial";
```

I get an error because the font attribute doesn't want a string but a Font. So how can I set the font to Arial programmatically?

Answer (score 24):

This works:

```
label.GetComponent<Text> ().font = Resources.GetBuiltinResource(typeof(Font), "Arial.ttf") as Font;
```

Comment: Can also be simplified to: Resources.GetBuiltinResource<Font>("Arial.ttf")

Answer (score 1):

try to create a public variable of type Font in the editor.

```
public Font myNewFont;
```

then you can do something like

```
label.GetComponent<Text>().font= myNewFont;
```

Not able to test it, but I think it should work, here's a very similar question... 
[How to change Font type in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374384/how-to-change-font-type-in-unity)

Comment: But I want to use Arial. Not my font

Comment: I think arial is the default value, but if not.. you can assign the font Arial in the myNewFotn variable or do :
`label.GetComponent<Text>().font = Resources.GetBuiltinResource(typeof(Font), "Arial.ttf") as Font
`
this is described in the other post that I've shared with you

Comment: By default the font is none